# My application deployed on Vercel can't be found

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, deployment, vercel

Good morning everybody. Thank you for your previous really helpful answers. But I have currently another error: The deployement of my Dashboard Next app was a succes but when I try visit it the browser display me an error. Like this :

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/f96tk.png)

I don't know how to solve that because I don't know what is wrong with the code.

I try to reopen the app but it has not changed. Always the same error

Comment: you should add how have you deployed, steps that you followed and any errors under console or vercel logs if any .. The image attached is not so helpful